# No installed app with label 'app_name' error message

Tags: python-3.x, django-3.0

When I try to makemigrations of my models on my new project with Django, I receive an error message,>No installed app with label 'app_name', what could be the issue and how can I fix it.?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO. Your question is pretty brief, have you tried putting that error message in a search engine and reading through some of the results?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Django settings.py and put your app: "app_name" into INSTALLED_APPS.
If it doesn't work still, then check your syntax in models.py.